How would you configure anycast for servers located in different data centers around the globe on a service such as CloudFlare?
According to CloudFlare's documentation (https://www.cloudflare.com/en-ca/learning/dns/what-is-anycast-dns/) and documentation from other DNS service providers anycast works by allowing multiple servers on the network to use the same IP address.
With the following scenario of having 3 servers in different data centers in the world having different IP addresses with a domain of example.com:

US: 1.1.1.1
Europe: 2.2.2.2
Asia: 3.3.3.3

How would the DNS records be setup for example.com on a service such as CloudFlare or another DNS provider?
CloudFlare for example provides a list of anycast IPs: https://www.cloudflare.com/en-ca/ips/, would picking a random IP address from one of their provided ranges and creating the following DNS records work?
For example, this IP address range is shown: 103.21.244.0/22, using an IP address of: 103.21.244.1, would DNS records be set up in the following manner?



Type
Name
Content




A
example.com
103.21.244.1


A
?
1.1.1.1


A
?
2.2.2.2


A
?
3.3.3.3



Would BGP be needed to be setup on the servers themselves using software such as Bird with the anycast IP: 103.21.244.1?

What problem are you attempting to solve? You want DNS to resolve differently in different parts of the world? If so, that has nothing to do with DNS servers using anycast. In that case you simply need a DNS provider that supports this scenario for you. Or do you want to use anycast on your own service? In short; describe the problem you're attempting to solve, not what you believe the solution is.
